# Image pixel distort in ImageView Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments, android-imageview

I am working with an application in which I have more work with images. I want to show profile pictures and Article images in my app. For article images I have tried **scale type** of `ImageView` to "fitcenter or centercrop or fitxy" but nothing works fine. My image pixel's are distorted. I am using **Glide** library to show image on sever. I have even tried `.fitcenter()` etc. Glide methods but nothing works so that my image work fine with `ImageView`.

#### Code:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgArticle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_image" />
```

#### Glide Code:

```
Glide.with(context).load(articleList.get("article_image"))
        .thumbnail(0.5f)
        .placeholder(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blank_image))
        .fitCenter()
        .into(imgBanner);
```

I have tried various methods i.e. fitcenter, centercrop etc. but nothing works.

[image: Below is my image i.e. how its looks on device]

Comment: try with static hight width in your imageview

Answer (score 0):

`android:scaleType="fitXY"` will stretch your image. You can try this code so that image will not stretch.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgArticle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_image" />
```

Or you can adjust the height and width as per your UI

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgArticle"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:src="@drawable/blank_image" />
```